# asp.mvc 4 EF ActionResult Edit with not all fields in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The standard generated code bock for responding to the Edit save form

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(User user)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
 return View(user);
}
```

works when all fields are present in the edit view.

In my model I have a password field that (for obvious reasons) I don't want to pass as an invisible form field. 
As a result password is null (which is to be expected).
How should I code to handle this scenario?

1. get the password value, should I fetch the value from the database?
   if I use: User u = db.User.Find(user.ID); EF has issues with "an object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager"
2. how do I tackle the ModelState.IsValid as it is false

I have found answers for previous mvc versions, but was wondering what is the most elegant / efficient way of achieving this?

@freeride, surly I don't have to test if user.Password is null, I expect it to be null and if it isn't then it was injected by a malicious user. The entire excersie was to avoid user manipulation of the password.

Removing the password field (ModelState.Remove("Password");) does solve the ModelState validation issue.
Now remains the question, how do I restore the password value? Following works:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(user user)
{
    user v = db.Users.Find(user.ID);
    ModelState.Remove("Pass");


    user.Password = v.Password;           // assign from db 

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        //db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified; // this won't work as the context changed
        db.Entry(v).CurrentValues.SetValues(user); // we need to use this now
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(user);
}
```

I wonder if I'm obliged to do an extra db trip to fetch the value? I had to change the code to fix the EF context change, it works, but is the code right?

Comment: can you paste your view code here please... i would think that if you delete your password field from your view , it should not have any problem while saving

Comment: @patel.milanb, there is no password field in the view as I removed it.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, this is without any doubt the official way to go, but creating a view model to just leave out one field on a form of a dozen seems a lot of overhead, I was wondering if there existed a workable shortcut.

Comment: Yes, it exist, but I won't show it because I hate preaching bad practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
```

add

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Password))
{
    ModelState.Remove("Password");
}
```

> I wonder if I'm obliged to do an extra db trip to fetch the value? I
>   had to change the code to fix the EF context change, it works, but is
>   the code right?

Do it in a different way. Don't use an entity object as your model.
Create a model which contains only data you need to update,for example:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}
```

and now:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(UserModel userModel)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(userModel.Id);
        user.FirstName = userModel.FirstName ;
        user.Surname  = userModel.Surname;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(userModel);
}
```

I hope it helps.