# Multiple Model In MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am learning how to use MVC right now and I just have a question on when I am creating and updating entries in the database. I was reading a post from this page: [asp.mvc 4 EF ActionResult Edit with not all fields in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469262/asp-mvc-4-ef-actionresult-edit-with-not-all-fields-in-view)

The guy in it said to create a model that will be used, so is the efficient way to insert a new row and update an existing row by having two models with different properties?

So my models would look like this -

```
public class UserModelView
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime AccountCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastLoggedIn { get; set; }
}

public class UserModelCreate
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime AccountCreated { get; set; }
}

public class UserModelUpdate
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastLoggedIn { get; set; }
}
```

Is this the best way to do what I need to do?

Comment: so what is your question ???

Comment: Is this the best way to do what I need to do?

Comment: For such simple model maybe it may not be clear but...in general yes (it's the way to do it). Model should have only what you use and nothing more (don't forget you can use inheritance to avoid duplicated code). It'll keep your controller methods and your views safer and much clean (and slightly faster but you shouldn't really care about this).

Comment: Imagine a more complex scenario: you create a Customer (id and name), you may delete it (id only), view it (name, list of Orders) and update it (name only). Model will always tell you exactly what you need.

Comment: Yeah, well I have a much bigger model I am actually working on, but to keep the post small I just made a quick example, I was just wondering if this is the best way to go about doing it.

Comment: Yes, it is! You may relax this guideline (nothing is written on the stone) for very simple models but in general this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you were previously using the entity class when binding your model back in.

**You shouldn't do that!**

The guy in the post is right, this is a much better way of controlling your entity and model information and provides a layer of seperation between the two.

After all you wouldnt want a user being able to directly manipulate an entity via a HTTP request.

I answered something similar  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659828)